# remove a value of a dic without removing the key

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that has list as values. now I randomly select a value out the list when the value is picked the value must be removed. so they are not used again, but the key and outer values must stay.

## this not my code. simplify it to explain it.

```
dic1 ={1:[[0,1],[1,1]],2:[[0,1],[1,1]]}

for key,value in dic1.items():
  if key == 2:
    # for example, I want to delete from key 2: list element [0,1]
    # so key 1 : [0,1] stays
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't loop, dictionaries are made to avoid `O(n)` loops:

```
dic1 ={1:[[0,1],[1,1]],2:[[0,1],[1,1]]}
```

Access the dictionary by key: you get the reference on the value. Since you know which data is inside it, you can remove first list item by:

```
dic1[2].pop(0)
```

Of course, you'd have to write it more safely in the general case:

```
k = 2
value = dic1.get(2,None) # returns None if key not found
if isinstance(value,list) and value: # this is a list, and not empty
    value.pop(0)
else:
    # error message
    print("Warning: nothing done")
```